# Views Global: PHP can't get variable

Tags: views, entities

I need to get **field_ip_serwera** from node in table views using global PHP. For now it doesn't work :-(

```
if(function_exists('fsockopen')){
$language = array(
    'serveronline' => '<img alt="" height="16" src="/sites/default/files/user-online.png" width="16" />.',
    'serveroffline' => '<img alt="" height="16" src="/sites/default/files/user-offline.png" width="16" />.',
);
$timeout = 1;

$adres = $row->field_ip_serwera;
$pport = "27015";

$server = array(
    'check' => true,             
    'ip' => "$adres",      
    'port' => "$pport",             
);

$output = "";

if ($server['check']) {
    if ($fp = @fsockopen($server['ip'], $server['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout)) {
        fclose($fp);
        $serveronline = true;
        $output .= "<p>\n";
        $output .= "  ".$language['serveronline']."\n";
        $output .= "</p>\n";
    } else {
        $serveronline = false;
        $output .= "<p>\n";
        $output .= "  ".$language['serveroffline']."\n";
        $output .= "</p>\n";
    }
}
return $output;
}
else { echo'Funkcja <b>fsockopen</b> nie jest dostępna na Twoim serwerze...'; }
```

My english is poor, examples plx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump` to check the content inside the variable `$row`

But maybe you can use this variable to get what you need:

```
$row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_ip_serwera['und'][0]['value'];
```

As long as that field belongs to the node you're using in that View